# Compiling httpd/apache2 fails with link error for libexpat.la

Tags: apache-2.2, unix, redhat, httpd

I'm trying to install httpd by compiling from source.  I get the following error:

```
libtool: link: cannot find the library `/usr/local/apr/lib/libexpat.la'
```

`locate libexpat` does yield the following but configure seems to be looking in the wrong place.  I think libtool is used to manage these links.  My question is how can I specify the path to `libexpat.la`?

Comment: what distro & architecture?

Answer (score -1):

Take a look here:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189906/upgrade-subversion-143-to-152-on-debian-hosted-account#330061

It's the same issue, just different library, should help you.

Note for the future: it would be better to ask these kinds of questions on stackoverflow.com.

Comment: Thanks.  I actually asked a similar question a fortnight ago on StackOverflow and was told to post here in future.  Appreciate your help though, cheers.

Comment: :) Strange... This is a programming issue... Did the above solve your issue or not?

Comment: how is an error when installing from source a programming issue?

Comment: @iainlbc Well, people who write programs usually compile them in order to run them and usually run into the problems like the OPs problem much more often then people who don't program, so yes it is. We can cast all sorts of doubts about whether it is or it's not - in my world, it's definitively more a programming issue then a server, network or a desktop PC relates issue (FAQ anyone? http://serverfault.com/faq). YMMV.